# Create / Update / Delete items in Sitecore via GraphQL

Tags: graphql

The Sitecore Headless [GraphQL documentation](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/graphql/graphql-overview) has some good examples for querying data. However I don't see any for mutations such as updating an item's fields, creating new items, or deleting items.

As an example, say I have an item of template Listing which has a field called description. How do I update the field? I tried this but I think the syntax is wrong.

```
mutation UpdateListing($path: String, $description String) {
    item(path: $path) {
        id
        ...on Listing {
            description {
                value: $description
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `systemContent` schema provider built into Sitecore GraphQL does indeed provide mutations to `createItem`, `updateItem`, and `deleteItem`. The Sitecore-provided `/sitecore/api/graph/items/master` endpoint exposes these, and details can be found in the Schema Docs in the GraphQL IDE accessible at `/sitecore/api/graph/items/master/ui`.

Note that for these to work successfully, the context user executing them must have appropriate authorizations. If you are using the `systemService` security configuration on the endpoint (the default for the example), you may need [additional configuration](/questions/29589/getting-authorization-required-error-when-attempting-to-use-systemservice-with/29590) for it to authenticate using cookies. If using `publicService` or otherwise authenticating with an API Key, the Impersonation User configured on the API Key will need appropriate rights.

Note as well that when setting item field values, the mutations accept a value of type `FieldValueInput`, which expects a JSON value for the field value. The docs on this graph type provide examples of accepted values:

| Field type | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Checkbox | `"true"`, `"false"` |
| Integer | `"5"` |
| Number | `"5.5"` |
| Single-Line Text | `"'Home'"` |
| Multi-Line Text, Rich Text | `"'line1\r\nline2'"` |
| Date and Datetime | `"'2019-08-04T13:33:03.969Z'"` |
| Checklist | `["0DD426E8-F61B-447E-8484-A1FF33115963","B3576ED6-05C9-49E7-B12B-918D5B2CF430"]` |
| General Link | `"{'text':'some test', 'anchor': 'anchor', 'linktype':'internal','queryString':'sc_lang=en','className': 'linkClass', 'targetItem':'110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9', 'target':'target', 'url': 'some url'}"` |

*Note the nested double/single quotes on text values in particular, to make them valid JSON.*

### Example Queries

#### Create Item

```
mutation CreateItem {
  createItem(
    name: "ExampleItem"
    template: "{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}"
    parent: "{0DE95AE4-41AB-4D01-9EB0-67441B7C2450}"
    language: "en"
    fields: [
      { name: "title", value: "'Example Item'" }
      { name: "text", value: "'This is an example item created with GraphQL'" }
    ]
  ) {
    path
  }
}
```

#### Update Item

```
mutation UpdateItem {
  updateItem(
    path: "/sitecore/content/ExampleItem"
    language: "en"
    version: 1
    fields: [{ name: "title", value: "'Example Item with changed title'" }]
  ) {
    ... on SampleItem {
      title {
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Delete Item

```
mutation DeleteItem {
  deleteItem(
    path: "/sitecore/content/ExampleItem"
  )
}
```

Answer (score -3):

GraphQL is a querying "language". You cannot update or create sitecore items using it. What are you trying to do? Creating items in Sitecore from a JSS Front-end seems like a bad idea. I am assuming this is JSS front-end. What is your use case here?