# GraphQL Mutation to update DropLink and MultiList field types

Tags: graphql

From what I'm reading these fields aren't supported?
[Create / Update / Delete items in Sitecore via GraphQL](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/29581/create-update-delete-items-in-sitecore-via-graphql)

Is there a way to get this to work that someone's found anywhere? We Essentially just want to store GUID or Pipe-seperated GUIDs yeah? Trying to do so doesn't seem to work? Using Sitecore 10.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Dave, you're sort of right that these fields are not supported..."out of the box"? We just did this for another field type `TreeList` which is similar to `MultiList`.

You can add fields to the GraphQL service by creating a patch file to modify the Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.config. Under the `Content > fieldTypeMappings > inputTypeMapping` section, you add mapping to another field type.

The config patch file could look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
        <api>
            <GraphQL>
                <defaults>
                    <content>
                        <fieldTypeMappings>
                            <inputTypeMapping type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.Mutations.FieldTypeToJsonTypeMapper, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content">
                                <typeMapping hint="raw:AddTypeMapping">
                                    <map field="treelist" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.Mutations.JsonFields.JsonChecklistField, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content" />
                                </typeMapping>
                            </inputTypeMapping>
                        </fieldTypeMappings>
                    </content>
                </defaults>
            </GraphQL>
        </api>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

The data need to be sent as an array to add multiple item GUIDs to the field. Your GraphQL query would by similar to this:

```
mutation UpdateItem {
  updateItem(
    path: "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-5771ad6ed443"
    fields: [
        {name: "myMultilistFieldName", value: [
            "ffffffff-0611-aaaa-8aa9-0b819239a15a",
            "eeeeeeee-5fdb-bbbb-a48a-4326b94c7ffa",
            "dddddddd-cba4-cccc-a4e9-a3108e538d93",
            "cccccccc-e300-dddd-bdd3-6eb182cf8018",
            "bbbbbbbb-c2df-eeee-87a5-c90a152f77be",
            "aaaaaaaa-c389-ffff-b4b9-62f51f39daa2"
            ] }
    ]
  )
}
```

So, when you do your query search, you can see the results list as a string (value) and in an array (targetIds) this way:

```
Items: items {
        Item: item {
          id
          locationGroup {
              value
              targetIds
            }
          }
        }
```

As far as your need to do this for `DropLink`, you should be able to just add another field mapping to the same patch config file similar to that of the out-of-the-box `general link` mapping:

```
<map field="droplink" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.Mutations.JsonFields.JsonGeneralLinkField, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content" />
```

Hope this helps you out.